# App with Event logger on port:8080 listening calls from API port:8090 in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, backend

I'm trying to create an app with notification service whenever a call is made on API.
Is it possible for me to create a logger on port:8080 and when app is run on the server it listens to api running on another server.
Both applications are run on local machine for testing purposes using Docker.

So far I've been reading https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging in order to implement it but I'm having problems with understanding the path mapping.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's name the two applications:

1. API - the API service that you want to monitor
2. Monitor - which wants to see what calls are made to (1)

There are several ways to achieve this.

a) Open up a socket on Monitor for inbound traffic.  Communicate the IP address and socket port  manually to the API server, have it open up the connection to the Monitor and send some packet of data down this "pipe".  This is the lowest level approach simple, but very fragile as you have to coordinate the starting of the services, and decide on a "protocol" for how the applications exchange data.

b) REST: Create a RESTful controller on the Monitor app that accepts a POST.   Communicate the IP address and port manually to the API server.  Initiate a POST request to the Monitor app when needed.  This is more robust but still suffers from needing careful starting of the servers

c) Message Queue. install a message queue system like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ (available in Docker containers).  API server **publishes** a message to a **Queue**.  Monitor **subscribes** to the Queue.  Must more robust, still requires each application to be advised of the address of the MQ server, but now you can stop/start the two applications in any order

d) The java logging article is good started into java logging. Most use cases log to a local file on the local server. There are some implementations of backend logging that send logs to remote places (I don't think that article covers them), and there are ways of adding your own custom receiver of this log traffic.  In this option, on the API side, it would use ordinary logging code with no knowledge of the downstream consumption of the logging.  Your monitor app would need to integrate tightly into a particular logging system with this approach.